response error when working on jupyter notebook for the purpose of extracting data on tweeter
tweets = []
try:
     response_json = connect_to_endpoint(search_url, headers, params)
    print("Response received successfully.")
except Exception as e:
    print(f"An error occurred: {e}")
    response_json = {}

ERROR IM GETTING
 File <string>:4
    print("Response received successfully.")
                                            ^
IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level

need to get the code RIGHT
